# Python storing output as variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

I'm working on some data parsing from text files, by running a for-loop/conditionacross the files and writing output to result file. I then run another for-loop on that result file to parse it further.

Is there a way to store this result in a variable rather than a file?

Comment: What have you tried? Saving stuff as a variable is pretty easy in Python. If you have a text file, you can literally do `with open('file.txt', 'r') as f: cool_variable_name = f.read().split('\n')` and bam! variable!

Answer (score -1):

Yes but more context on what you want to accomplish would be helpful.

See below for what I think you want. This loop iterates over each item and then appends each one to a list which contains all outputs

```
lst = []
for x in range(0,5):
   y = x
   lst.append(y)
```